# Node.js assignment to const variable error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const url='https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Los%20Angeles.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FtLWhhd2t6IiwiYSI6ImNrMDl2YXU4aTBieTEzY252aHpvZHd5Y3YifQ.v8Xh5bZiNbkTR7FlQwIgYQ'                                                     request=({url:url, json:true}, (error,response) =>{
const latitude = response.body.features[0].center[0]
const longitude = response.body.features[0].center[1]
console.log(latitude,longitude) })
```

Here I used an api to geocode my location but I'm getting a TypeError: Assigment to const variable. According to me that error should only come when the const value is changing in the code but it's staying the same throughout then where is the problem?

Comment: You are missing an ```=``` in the first line after url

Comment: @MohammedAmirAnsari that must've been misplaced during copying the code but it is there and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Could you update the code and make sure it's correct, please.

Comment: @Hamza was doing that only :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an extra `=` sign in your code, try this:

```
const url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Los%20Angeles.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FtLWhhd2t6IiwiYSI6ImNrMDl2YXU4aTBieTEzY252aHpvZHd5Y3YifQ.v8Xh5bZiNbkTR7FlQwIgYQ';

request({ url: url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
  const latitude = response.body.features[0].center[0];
  const longitude = response.body.features[0].center[1];
  console.log(latitude,longitude);
})
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, why does the question not show a problem with this?